# MPI_Get not working properly in Parent/Children context

Tags: c++, mpi

Recently in class, we've been learning about a new way to use MPI, with the Parent/Children approach. We were tasked with implementing a really simple matrix/vector multiplication in C/C++, and realise benchmarks on a cluster. We're using OpenMPI 4.0.3.

I tried to implement a "pooling" system (Children pick a certain amount of work, do it, then put the result back on the master thread, and check if there's more work to do). To do so, I simply created a infinite loop, and the first thing a child does, is to fetch the current *offset*. While the *offset* is lower than the total number of vectors to process, it updates the *offset* on the parent thread, fetch the vectors, process them, ...

To fetch the *offset*, I created a dedicated *MPI_Win*, that children can use to fetch/update the value. The thing is, the *MPI_Get* call dosen't seem to update the value of the *offset* on the children threads.

Here are simplified versions of the code I wrote (mine contains a lot of logs, write results to a file, ...).

parent.cpp:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Init MPI
    int pid = -1, nprocs = -1;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
    assert(nprocs == 1);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);
    assert(pid == 0);

    // Read CLI arguments
    const unsigned int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    const unsigned int m = atoi(argv[2]);
    const unsigned int root = atoi(argv[4]);
    assert(root < nprocs);
    const unsigned int nslave = atoi(argv[5]);
    const std::string name = argv[6];
    const std::string slave_name = argv[7];

    // Define size constants
    const size_t nn = n * n;
    const size_t mn = m * n;

    // Spawning slaves & merging Comm
    int intrapid = -1;
    MPI_Comm intercom = nullptr, intracom = nullptr;
    MPI_Comm_spawn(slave_name.c_str(), argv, nslave,
                   MPI_INFO_NULL, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                   &intercom, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
    MPI_Intercomm_merge(intercom, 0, &intracom);
    MPI_Comm_rank(intracom, &intrapid);

    // Initialize & broadcast matrix
    int *matrix = new int[nn];
    srand(time(nullptr));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nn; i++) matrix[i] = rand() % MATRIX_MAX;
    MPI_Bcast(matrix, nn, MPI_INT, root, intracom);

    // initialize result and offset
    int offset = 0;
    int *results = new int[mn];

    // Initialize and generate vectors
    int *vectors = new int[mn];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) generate_vector(n, vectors + (i * n), rand() % (n / 2));

    // Allocate windows
    MPI_Win vectors_win = nullptr, results_win = nullptr, offset_win = nullptr;
    MPI_Win_create(vectors, mn, sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, intracom, &vectors_win);
    MPI_Win_create(results, mn, sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, intracom, &results_win);
    MPI_Win_create(&offset, 1, sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, intracom, &offset_win);

    // Fence to wait for windows initialization
    MPI_Win_fence(MPI_MODE_NOPRECEDE, vectors_win);

    // Start chrono while slaves fetch & compute
    Time debut = NOW;

    // Fence to wait for all vectors to be computed
    MPI_Win_fence(MPI_MODE_NOSUCCEED, results_win);

    // Write results to file, free memory, finalize
    // ...

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

child.cpp:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int pid = -1, intraprid = -1, nprocs = -1;
    MPI_Comm intercom = nullptr, intracom = nullptr;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
    assert(nprocs >= 1);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);
    assert(pid >= 0 && pid < nprocs);

    // Get communicator for intra-process communication through merge
    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&intercom);
    MPI_Intercomm_merge(intercom, 1, &intracom);
    MPI_Comm_rank(intracom, &intraprid);
    assert(intraprid >= 0);

    // Read CLI arguments
    const unsigned int n = atoi(argv[2]);
    const unsigned int m = atoi(argv[3]);
    const unsigned int batch_sz = atoi(argv[4]);
    const unsigned int root = atoi(argv[5]);
    assert(root < nprocs);

    // Define size constant
    const size_t nn = n * n;

    // Allocate matrix memory & fetch from master
    int *matrix = new int[nn];
    MPI_Bcast(matrix, nn, MPI_INT, root, intracom);

    // Allocate batch memory
    int *batch = new int[batch_sz * n];

    // Initialize dull windows (to match master initialization)
    MPI_Win vectors_win = nullptr, results_win = nullptr, offset_win = nullptr;
    MPI_Win_create(nullptr, 0, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, intracom, &vectors_win);
    MPI_Win_create(nullptr, 0, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, intracom, &results_win);
    MPI_Win_create(nullptr, 0, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, intracom, &offset_win);

    // Fence to wait for windows initialization
    MPI_Win_fence(MPI_MODE_NOPRECEDE, vectors_win);

    int offset = -1, new_offset = -1;
    // Infinite loop (break on first condition when no more vectors to process)
    while (true) {
        // Get offset from master
        MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, root, 0, offset_win);
        MPI_Get(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, root, 0, 1, MPI_INT, offset_win);
        // If offset is -1, something went wrong with the previous MPI_Get, but MPI_SUCCESS was returned
        assert(offset >= 0);
        // Break if no more vectors to process
        if (new_offset >= m - 1 || offset >= m - 1) {
            MPI_Win_unlock(root, offset_win);
            break;
        }

        // Get quantity of vectors to process (if not enough, get all remaining)
        const size_t sz = (offset + batch_sz > m) ? m - offset : batch_sz;
        // if sz > batch_sz, the received buffer will be overflown
        assert(sz <= batch_sz);

        // Compute the new vector offset for the other slaves
        new_offset = offset + sz;
        // Update the offset on master
        MPI_Put(&new_offset, 1, MPI_INT, root, 0, 1, MPI_INT, offset_win);
        MPI_Win_unlock(root, offset_win);

        // Fetch the batch of vectors to process
        MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_SHARED, root, 0, vectors_win);
        MPI_Get(batch, sz * n, MPI_INT, root, offset * n, sz * n, MPI_INT, vectors_win);
        MPI_Win_unlock(root, vectors_win);

        // Process the batch
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
            // ... matrix multiplication
        }

        // Put the result in the results window of the master
        MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, root, 0, results_win);
        MPI_Put(&batch, sz * n, MPI_INT, root, offset, sz * n, MPI_INT, results_win);
        MPI_Win_unlock(root, results_win);
    }

    // Fence to wait for all vectors to be computed
    MPI_Win_fence(MPI_MODE_NOSUCCEED, results_win);

    // Free memory, finalize
    // ...

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is that the assertion `assert(offset >= 0)` at the beginning of the child while loop is triggered (and logs show that *offset* is still -1, or whatever it was initialised with). Given that the offset starts at 0 on the parent thread, it means that the variable was not updated, but the call to *MPI_Get* returned MPI_SUCCESS. I though about a concurrency problem, but it seems that the lock works fine, as the children wait for the previous one to crash before entering the lock.

I've tried to resolve the problem, but given the lack of a clear documentation, I didn't succeed. I either made a stupid typo that I didn't catch, or there's something specific about this approach that I'm not aware of.

If someone has an idea about what I did wrong, I'd gladly accept it. Please excuse me for any english mistakes, I'm quite tired.

*Edit*: As requested, I switched names to "Parent/Children", instead of the old terminology

*Edit 2*: As it's been pointed out, the fences here are useless. I'm aware of this, they just come from the previous version of the code that I used as boilerplate code.

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the S-word. Every modern style guide argues against using it.

Comment: You are being very ambitious, using both spawning and one-sided together. If you want to do one-sided communication I would simplify this code by having a manager & worker subroutine, and then based on the rank calling the one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for switching terminology. I like "parent/child". Personally I use "manager/worker".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your big problem is that you immediately use the variable you retrieve with `MPI_Get`. That is not possible the way you do it. This variable only has its value after you release the lock, or after you do a synchronization call. Because you release the lock conditionally, I would insert `MPI_Win_flush_local` after the `MPI_Get` call, to ensure coherence between results on the target and origin.

EDIT. Another thing is that you mix active (`fence`) and passive (`lock`) target synchronization. In your code the fence doesn't do anything, so remove it. A fence would be appropriate if all children do the same number of gets or puts: then the closing fence of the epoch would ensure coherence of data on origin/target.

Comment: It partially resolved the problem. I added `MPI_Win_flush_local(root, offset_win)` after the `MPI_Get` and now the _offset_ is correct,  but now it seems like the children ignore the lock, and some read the same value

Comment: Nevermind, the only _offset_ duplicated is the last one (the one exiting the loop), which is completely correct.